# Control-Enter doesn't work in ESS?

Tags: ess, aquamacs

I checked my ess/lisp/ess-mode.el file and it has the line of code I'm expecting for this to work (below). Anyone know why this would happen?

```el
(define-key map [(control return)] 'ess-eval-region-or-line-and-step)
```

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question but try global-set-key or google for it and that is how I have set my keybindings for ess-evaluating and it works

Comment: What does `<f1> c C-<return>` tell you?

Comment: @npostavs It tells me c-enter is not defined but I have that line above in my code... I've tried doing googling and other normal ess commands work. such as /C-c /C-c

Comment: Nevermind I'm a n00b, it was because I was synchronizing ess with an out of date emacs

Comment: @AlexCh :  please either post an answer or delete the question.